# What is the simplest way to restrict access to certain site pages?

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress, security

I am looking at ways to restrict access to certain pages of a site for only a temporary period to allow only a certain subset of people.

I have the peoples email addresses and names.

I would much rather do this without the need for full fledged sign ups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to restrict access to a directory under Apache is to use a `Require` directive.  Here is a simple tutorial on how to set this up:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#auth

Note that use of groups is not required, you could simplify to use only usernames:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /www/passwords/password.file
Require valid-user
```

Comment: @AJ this is not a simple way btw

Comment: @diEcho what would be a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way.... create a unique string that only you know. And do this:

```
if ( array_key_exists('MY SECRET_STRING',$_GET) ) // allow access
```

Then email users a URL like: `http://www.example.com/?MY_SECRET_STRING`

If you want to get fancier you can use a cookie to store it so it persists across pages.

Disclaimer: You asked for the easiest not the most secure. If anyone gets a hold of the URL with the key in it then they WILL be able to see your site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a TRULY RANDOM NAME folder
2. Move the pages you want to this folder
3. Send an email to those people with the link to the folder
4. DO NOT add an entry in your robots.txt file
5. Remove the folder after this "temporary period"
6. DO NOT TELL ANYONE I TOLD YOU TO DO THIS!

P.S. security trough obscurity is **highly discourage** but in certain cases it's acceptable.